# Grid.Effect in Winrt

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In WPF there is an `Effect` property of most controls such as `Grid.Effect` which allows creating a blurred grid. I wanted to see how can I create a popup with a blurred background in WinRT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to not doing it or using DirectX might be to use the new `RenderTargetBitmap` class with the `RenderAsync()` method that allows you to get access to the pixels of the control from C# or VB level (assuming that is what you are using), which might be easier than DirectX and actually fast enough for some basic effects to run on the CPU. I've done it in the [`FxContentControl`](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/FxContentControl/FxContentControl.cs) in the WinRT XAML Toolkit last weekend and it seems to work OK in some simple scenarios with the main problem being - when to update the effect.

The control currently doesn't blur anything, but rather finds the expanded pixels of the content and makes them black, serving as a poor man's way to generate strokes for a `TextBlock` or for any other control with some transparent and some non-transparent areas. You could change it to blur or add an option to do it on demand fairly easily.

Here's the default style of the templated control:

```
<Style
    TargetType="controls:FxContentControl">
    <Setter
        Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
        Value="Left" />
    <Setter
        Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
        Value="Top" />
    <Setter
        Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate
                TargetType="controls:FxContentControl">
                <Grid>
                    <Image
                        x:Name="BackgroundFxImage"
                        Stretch="None"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="RenderedGrid"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Image
                        x:Name="ForegroundFxImage"
                        Stretch="None"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Imaging;

namespace WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls
{
    public class FxContentControl : ContentControl
    {
        private Image _backgroundFxImage;
        private Image _foregroundFxImage;
        private ContentPresenter _contentPresenter;
        private Grid _renderedGrid;

        public FxContentControl()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(FxContentControl);
        }

        protected override async void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _backgroundFxImage = this.GetTemplateChild("BackgroundFxImage") as Image;
            _foregroundFxImage = this.GetTemplateChild("ForegroundFxImage") as Image;
            _contentPresenter = this.GetTemplateChild("ContentPresenter") as ContentPresenter;
            _renderedGrid = this.GetTemplateChild("RenderedGrid") as Grid;

            if (_renderedGrid != null)
            {
                _renderedGrid.SizeChanged += this.OnContentPresenterSizeChanged;
            }

            if (_renderedGrid.ActualHeight > 0)
            {
                await this.UpdateFx();
            }
        }

        private async void OnContentPresenterSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs sizeChangedEventArgs)
        {
            await this.UpdateFx();
        }

        private async Task UpdateFx()
        {
            await this.UpdateBackgroundFx();
        }

        private async Task UpdateBackgroundFx()
        {
            if (_renderedGrid.ActualHeight < 1 ||
                _backgroundFxImage == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await rtb.RenderAsync(_renderedGrid);

            var pw = rtb.PixelWidth;
            var ph = rtb.PixelHeight;

            var wb = _backgroundFxImage.Source as WriteableBitmap;

            if (wb == null ||
                wb.PixelWidth != pw ||
                wb.PixelHeight != ph)
            {
                wb = new WriteableBitmap(pw, ph);
            }

            await ProcessContentImage(rtb, wb, pw, ph);

            _backgroundFxImage.Source = wb;
        }

        protected virtual async Task ProcessContentImage(RenderTargetBitmap rtb, WriteableBitmap wb, int pw, int ph)
        {
            var rtbBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
            var rtbPixels = rtbBuffer.GetPixels();
            var wbBuffer = wb.PixelBuffer;
            var wbPixels = wbBuffer.GetPixels();

            // Expand
            int expansion = 1;

            for (int x = 0; x < pw; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < ph; y++)
                {
                    int x1min = Math.Max(0, x - expansion);
                    int x1max = Math.Min(x + expansion, pw - 1);
                    int y1min = Math.Max(0, y - expansion);
                    int y1max = Math.Min(y + expansion, ph - 1);
                    //bool found = false;
                    byte maxa = 0;

                    for (int x1 = x1min; x1 <= x1max; x1++)
                        for (int y1 = y1min; y1 <= y1max; y1++)
                        {
                            var a = rtbPixels.Bytes[4 * (y1 * pw + x1) + 3];
                            if (a > maxa)
                                maxa = a;
                        }
                    wbPixels.Bytes[4 * (y * pw + x)] = 0;
                    wbPixels.Bytes[4 * (y * pw + x) + 1] = 0;
                    wbPixels.Bytes[4 * (y * pw + x) + 2] = 0;
                    wbPixels.Bytes[4 * (y * pw + x) + 3] = maxa;
                }

            wbPixels.UpdateFromBytes();
        }
    }
}
```

It also uses the following IBuffer wrapper:

```
﻿using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace WinRTXamlToolkit.Imaging
{
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming - This class extends IBuffer
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains extensions for an IBuffer interface in the context of a WriteableBitmap,
    /// which exposes one to access its pixels.
    /// </summary>
    public static class IBufferExtensions
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gives access to the pixels of a WriteableBitmap given an IBuffer
        /// exposed by Pixels property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Note that creating this object copies the pixels buffer
        /// into the Bytes byte array for quick pixel access
        /// and the array needs to be copied back to the pixels buffer
        /// to update the bitmap with a call to UpdateFromBytes().
        /// This is acceptable for convenience and possibly best for
        /// performance in some scenarios, but it does add some upfront
        /// overhead as well overhead to update the bitmap at the end.
        /// This is only a theory and for better performance it might be
        /// good to test different approaches.
        /// The goal of this approach is code simplicity. For best performance
        /// using native code and/or DirectX is recommended.
        /// </remarks>
        public class PixelBufferInfo
        {
            private readonly Stream _pixelStream;

            /// <summary>
            /// The bytes of the pixel stream.
            /// </summary>
            public byte[] Bytes;

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PixelBufferInfo" /> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="pixelBuffer">The pixel buffer returned by WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.</param>
            public PixelBufferInfo(IBuffer pixelBuffer)
            {
                _pixelStream = pixelBuffer.AsStream();
                this.Bytes = new byte[_pixelStream.Length];
                _pixelStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                _pixelStream.Read(this.Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
                //this.Pixels = bytes.ToPixels();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Updates the associated pixel buffer from bytes.
            /// </summary>
            public void UpdateFromBytes()
            {
                _pixelStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                _pixelStream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the pixels access wrapper for a PixelBuffer property of a WriteableBitmap.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pixelBuffer">The pixel buffer.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static PixelBufferInfo GetPixels(this IBuffer pixelBuffer)
        {
            return new PixelBufferInfo(pixelBuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlirezaNoori--I still stand behind my answer that the blur is not there for a design reason and that introducing it not only is clearly inconsistent with other Windows Store applications, it's not efficient to create or store (as you've created a potentially extremely large bitmap (W * H * 4 bytes) and then process each pixel to "blur" it). It's work that can be done efficiently by a GPU, not a CPU.

Comment: Of course GPU is the ideal solution here, but I provided an alternative solution that may be applicable. From my testing - blurring a 1920x1080 `RenderTargetBitmap` into a `WriteableBitmap` on my machine takes about 1s. We have two 8MB bitmaps then and it might be 10x slower on some ARM devices based on my previous experience, but it is still something worth considering in some scenarios. I wouldn't worry so much about being consistent with other Windows Store apps if the point of your app is to be different or to blur backgrounds or maybe if it is a game with distinct design.

Answer (score 2):

Effects are not supported in WinRT in XAML.  You can use DirectX interop and put shaders there using C++ (SwapChainPanel).

Comment: Thank you. That much complexity doesn't worth going into.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, `Effect`s are not available currently in WinRT.

Ideas:

1. I'd suggest considering not creating a blurred background effect as it would not be a consistent experience across Windows Store applications. `Effect`s, at least in the Widows Application Store "[design language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/dn439959)" just aren't a good match.
2. Alternatively, you could just overlay a semi-transparent image with some noise to it to give a feeling at least of a non-uniform effect (rather than just a solid color made partially transparent).
3. Or, maybe just "darken" the background (again, an overlay would make this easy enough) to give a more "lightbox" style effect.
4. While you may be able to use interop, that likely increases the complexity of your application dramatically, especially when it's for a simple feature such as this.

Comment: I'm currently using a dark overlay as you mentioned. I'm with you on your first point though. You're right. It's funny I spent a lot of time watching BUILD sessions and reading articles about Metro design but suddenly I decided I wanted to do this :D